# In single click popup not opening?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-component

[image]

When clicking on the first input cell, the popup opens and closes correctly. However, closing the initial input and opening another results in the orange mark icon appearing, but the popup doesn't open until the second click. This issue persists across all input cells. where the popup opens only after the single click, Any assistance on resolving this, would be appreciated.

when open popup close using outside click is working fine

Component file ->

```
<tr v-for="(row, index) in table" :key="index">
  <td class="dot_td">
    <img :src="row.cell1.imgSrc" />
  </td>
  <th v-html="row.cell2.content">
  </th>
  <td v-for="inputCell in row.inputCells" :key="inputCell.input" :class="inputCell.rectification === 1 ? 'border_td' : ''">
    <input v-bind="inputCell.input" :value="inputCell.inputData">
    <a style="cursor: pointer;" class="request_icon" @click="openPopup($event, inputCell)">
      <svg width="14" height="13" viewBox="0 0 14 13" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <path d="M13.5 6.5C13.5 9.77946 10.6254 12.5 7 12.5C3.37461 12.5 0.5 9.77946 0.5 6.5C0.5 3.22054 3.37461 0.5 7 0.5C10.6254 0.5 13.5 3.22054 13.5 6.5Z"
        stroke="#CDCDCD" />
        <path d="M6.46866 10V4.54545H7.53045V10H6.46866ZM7.00488 3.70384C6.82022 3.70384 6.66161 3.64228 6.52903 3.51918C6.39882 3.3937 6.33372 3.24455 6.33372 3.07173C6.33372 2.89654 6.39882 2.7474 6.52903 2.62429C6.66161 2.49882 6.82022 2.43608 7.00488 2.43608C7.18954 2.43608 7.34698 2.49882 7.47718 2.62429C7.60976 2.7474 7.67605 2.89654 7.67605 3.07173C7.67605 3.24455 7.60976 3.3937 7.47718 3.51918C7.34698 3.64228 7.18954 3.70384 7.00488 3.70384Z"
        fill="#CDCDCD" />
      </svg>
    </a>
  </td>
  <td>
    {{ row.totalCell.text }}
  </td>
</tr>
```

Script ->

```
<script setup>
const openPopup = (event, inputCell) => {
    const iconbtn = event.currentTarget;
    const popup = document.getElementById('request_popup');
    
    userComment.value = inputCell.commentData;
    UsercommentDate.value = inputCell.UsercommentDate;
    currentInputCell.value = inputCell;
    managerComment.value = inputCell.Managercomment;
    isPopupVisible.value = !isPopupVisible.value;
    const rect = iconbtn.getBoundingClientRect();

    if (isPopupVisible.value) {
        iconbtn.classList.add('requested');
        popupStyle.top = rect.bottom + window.scrollY + 'px';
        popupStyle.left = rect.left + window.scrollX + 'px';

        // Add an event listener to close the popup on outside click
        const closePopupOnOutsideClick = (event) => {
            const isClickInsidePopup = iconbtn.contains(event.target) || popup.contains(event.target);
            if (!isClickInsidePopup) {
                closePopup(iconbtn);
                document.removeEventListener('click', closePopupOnOutsideClick);
            }
        };

        document.addEventListener('click', closePopupOnOutsideClick);
        
    }else{
        isPopupVisible.value = false;
        iconbtn.classList.remove('requested');
    }
    
};

const closePopup = (iconbtn) => {
    isPopupVisible.value = false;
    if(iconbtn){
    iconbtn.classList.remove('requested');
    }
};
<script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating functionality to listen to click outside it will probably work better by just listening to a blur event `iconbtn.addEventListener('blur', closePopupOnOutsideClick);`